# Examples of Cocoa/Objective-C and Distributed Objects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, distributed-objects

I am learning Cocoa and Objective-C (well, and C) to make a few Mac apps I've had floating around. I need to use Distributed Objects, but am having trouble finding simple, concise examples. Does anybody know of any?

Comment: +1 this is indeed a mystery to me too

Comment: I just created [a more up to date answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36367753/105539) for 2016. This one is short and simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered [this project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bibdesk/) at SourceForge which is a fairly large Cocoa project. It uses bonjour and distributed objects, and other then that I've found it to be a good resource and example. Just thought I'd put that out there in case anybody comes across this question.

Answer (score 3):

A [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=distributed+objects+cocoa) came up with plenty of hits.  The [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html) are also good.  [Late Night Cocoa](http://www.mac-developer-network.com/podcasts/lnc/lnc020/) also has an episode on it.

Answer (score 2):

I maintain the comp.lang.objective-c FAQ, and there's an example in there: [How can I forward messages between remote objects](http://thaesofereode.info/clocFAQ/#cocoa-do)? It's very short but should give you the basic idea, on which you can then hang the Apple and GNUstep docs to which it links.

Answer (score 2):

It's a fairly old article but this is probably a good starting point for distributed objects. I  personally found it easier to start with the older tutorials and work my way up to the more recent ones which use new technologies such as Core Data.

http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000062.php