# Cocoa: Launch Agent with Objects?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

TLDR; is it possible to send/receive *objects* between an app and a 3rd party launch agent?

I'm writing an extension for an existing app (A). It's packaged and I do not have access to the source - but I can write simple plug-ins that can do some basic Cocoa and host a UI. Read: very limited options.

Ideally, what I'd like to do is have the plugin in app (A) message an external service (B) [sending objects], have (B) do some heavy lifting, then respond back to (A) so the UI can update.

I've been reading up on Launch Agents and they look promising, but I noted the examples all use basic types - no objects. I found [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367752/how-do-i-do-distributed-objects-on-osx-with-objective-c/36367753#36367753) discussing how to use Distributed Objects, but that's about it. It looks great, but what worries me is I'm not seeing a whole lot of current information on DO and I can't tell if it's something Apple will continue to support going forward.

Does anyone have any suggestions on options for a scenario like this? Maybe I'm just approaching this the wrong way?

Another option is I just completely split this out - write a separate full app and have (A) open it up with AppleScript. The UX wouldn't be as nice, but it would also work.

Thank you,
Eric

NOTE: I can't use NSTask. Or at least I've failed utterly to get it to work in this specific situation. Due to issues with app (A) it breaks when some of the methods run within the process. If I could somehow spawn NSTask so it was executing completely outside of (A) that might be an option. Which is actually what prompted me to look at Launch Agents...

Comment: DO is used internally by macOS and by a lot of developers in their apps, so it's probably not going away anytime soon. It's not too commonly used though, which is why it hasn't changed since it was originally released in Mac OS X 10.0.